# Function returns number, but object is stored

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3js to create a pie chart. I ran into a problem where I'm not able to print a number onto the screen though it returns successfully. Here's what I'm talking about:

```
$('svg').on("mouseenter","path",function() {
    var age = d3.select(this).each(function(d){return d.data.Life_Span});
    console.log(age)
    d3.select('.moreinfo').text(age)
});
```

`d.data.Life_Span` is the data I want to print on the screen. However, age does not store a number, just an object. I tried storing the data in a variable inside the inner function, but this didn't work. Is there an easy way to get this value? It seems like there's an easy solution out there, but my code always prints out `[object][object]`

Here's the full code: http://plnkr.co/edit/83Q8AFFgHama3LLpBI2C?p=preview

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `.each` ignores the return value of the callback: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_each .

Comment: In case you want to know *what* happened, so you don't make the same mistake again: D3 selections are objects in v4.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.each` ignores the return value of the callback. It is used to iterate over a selection of elements.

If you want to access the data bound to a specific element, you can use [`.datum`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_datum):

```
var age = d3.select(this).datum().data.Life_Span;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're associating `age` to a D3 selection. And, since the new D3 v4.x, all selections are objects:

> Selections no longer subclass Array using prototype chain injection; they are now plain objects, improving performance.

Thus, I believe you want just the value:

```
var age; 
d3.select(this).each(function(d){age = d.data.Life_Span});
d3.select('.moreinfo').text(age);
```

Here is your updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wyc2x9HX6Ddh5nHjcjh5?p=preview

**PS**: Just as in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530758/d3-pie-chart-problems-with-exiting-entering), I have to advise you: what you're doing right now (using `d3.each`, not to mention using jQuery...) is **not** the "D3 way" for doing what you want. You could simply get the bound datum when hovering over the path element, like this:

```
d3.selectAll('path').on("mouseover",function(d) {
    var age = d.data.Life_Span;
    d3.select('.moreinfo').html(age)
});
```

Here is the corresponding plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ouAPY6KLVenxXy83HKh9?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to follow your suggestion to get rid of jQuery, but can't seem to avoid using  `d3.each` in certain cases like selecting animals that belong to a certain category. In situations where you only need to filter data rather than bind it, is it ok to use `each`?

Comment: It depends on each (no pun intended) specific case.